# Sort text by value in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have lists of files that contain a few columns of data. It is not sorted the way I want from the output, so I'm manually hunting for where a line should be. Is there a way in Notepad++ to sort the lines alphabetically? If so, how?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Since [Notepad++ 6.5.2](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.5.2-release.html) it is now natively possible to sort lines:

[image: Version v6.9.2 (as of 8/5/16)]

Comment: @ScottRhee I updated for the same reason :)

Comment: note that any capital comes before a lower case. ie. A-Z then a-z

Comment: Thanks for including a screenshot! This other post (http://superuser.com/questions/762279/sorting-lines-in-notepad-without-the-textfx-plugin) is good, but it is very clear from your screenshot what to do.

Comment: It worked! This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is buggy... I had to copy my text and paste into another tab to be able to sort...

Comment: @Rosdi  same for me...appreciate your comment.

Comment: @Rosdi: What ***exactly*** isn't working? E.g., does it not sort at all?

Comment: STILL buggy and lacking case sensitivity clearly defined option. Why isn't this a feature? (case sensitivity ) (sort as decimal is workaround)? Really? It's a text editor that still has non-intuitive sorting issues. Hmm. I still prefer TextFX - it works and works fine.

Comment: I saw some problem with sorts, I *think* it can be linked with inconsistent line endings. One solution that helped me to solve the "non-sorting" issue was : *Select all text*, convert all line endings to Linux/Mac/Windows (whichever is **NOT** your operating system), then convert all line-endings to *your operating system ending*. Now It worked fine for me at this point.

Comment: @Pacopaco That's the only way it works for me. Without modifying the line endings (semicolons in my case), the sort does nothing.

Comment: One can also use "Sort Lines As Number Ascending" if you have timestamps in front of your every log entry.

Comment: In Notepad++ Version v7.9.1 the long awaited feature was implemented as changelog point "15. Add case **in**sensitive lines sorting."

Answer (score 49):

(Note that this answer was written before np++ 6.5.2 released.)

It seems that Notepad++ doesn't support sorting by default, but Notepad++ has many friends to do something like that for you which we call plugins.

1. Download TextFX plugin for Notepad++ ( [TextFX in SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/TextFX/) ) - go to the latest version and download the latest TextFX…bin.zip.
2. Open the zip and extract NppTextFX.dll to (Program Files)\Notepad++\plugins folder.
3. Restart Notepad++
4. To do the sort, select lines to sort, go to TextFX on the main menu and select TextFX Tools - Sort lines.

Comment: No need to grab TextFX manually -> First: Update to newest version of NPP. Then pick "Plugins" / "Plugin Manager". It should then populate plugin list. Pick TextFX. "Install". Done.

Comment: Also, native sorting has improved over the years. (Pick "Edit"/"Line Operations") See other answers if you don't want to bother w/ TextFX plugin, though, I recommend it for other reasons..

Comment: The plugin is now called "TextFX Characters".

Answer (score 6):

Since you are using Notepad++, I assume you are using Windows. You have a few other options to sort large text file content alphabetically.

My personal favorite is PowerShell. You could use the [Sort-Object cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176968.aspx). 
The following command shows an example of how to use the cmdlet. We first read the content (Get-Content) of MyFile.txt, pass it to the Sort-Object cmdlet (Sort) and output the result into a new file (Out-File).

```
Get-Content MyFile.txt | Sort | Out-File MySortedFile.txt
```

[image]

Another option is to use the [sort command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722869.aspx) in the Command Prompt.

```
sort MyFile.txt /o MySortedFile.txt
```

[image]

Finally, the last option is to use an online tool: [miniwebtool.com](http://miniwebtool.com) or [sortlines.com](https://sortlines.com) will do the job.