# Sorting lines in Notepad++ without the TextFX plugin

Tags: notepad++, plugins, sorting

The current version of Notepad++ (at the time of this writing) is 6.6.3. Version [6.5.2](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.5.2-release.html) is the first that introduced a native (without a plugin) sorting function. At least, that's what they claim; even though we're nine releases after version 6.5.2, I have found **nothing** about this feature:

- There is no sign of it in the menu (or I am blind),
- There isn't even a word in Notepad++ documentation (online help).

Everything I read around the Internet (including [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/724189/156554)) still talks about sorting lines using the TextFX plugin. There isn't anything about a native (QuickSort-based) function.

So: **How do I sort lines in Notepad++ without using the TextFX plugin?**

Answer (score 449, accepted):

The proper menu option is as follows.

For all versions prior to `6.8.3`:

> Menu *Edit* → *Line Operations* → *Sort Lines in Ascending* / *Descending Order*

For version `6.8.3` and following:

> Menu *Edit* → *Line Operations* → *Sort Lines Lexicographically Ascending* / *Descending*

> [image: Sort lines lexicographically]

Select a few lines to sort just the selection. If there's no selection, your entire file will be sorted.

Comment: Can't believe I've used Notepad++ for this long without knowing about this!

Comment: For some weird reason this didn't work for me. I'm on Windows but my text had LF line endings only (text pasted from browser). To work around it I had to convert all Line endings to Unix, then back to Windows, then the sort worked.

Comment: @pgr Notepad++ sorting mechanism should work on any line ending. If you can reproduce this behavior then this may classify as a bug.

Comment: @trejder The fact that I had to convert one way and then back tells me the real problem is Notepad++'s realization of what kind of document it's working with. Maybe pasted text that hasn't been saved yet is an edge case. But it's definitely a bug, yes.

Comment: This worked for me with 7.3.3. However, had to do Edit > Convert CASE to > lowercase as the first step. Used the feature to sort a huge list of email addresses, so not a case-sensitive scenario.

Comment: The next question could be [whether it is possible to sort in a case-insensitive way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606753)...

Comment: Not working for me!

Comment: @PeterMortensen The next goof question could be, why you asked that question on Stack Overflow, not on Super User? :>

Comment: The sort function is not working correctly, it sorts like this: addCartLink
bindPager
setItemsTitle
addTab

Comment: As of 7.5.9, this function is flat out broken and does nothing on my lines.

Comment: I noticed that the sort function only works when lines are separated by both a Carriage Return and  Line Feed, in that order. Using only one or the other will not allow for sorting, probably because Notepad thinks it's all one line.

Comment: V7.8.1 still works, , but french menu are "Édition/Ligne/Trier les lignes ..."

Comment: @Tharkon AFAIK Notepad++ supports all three line endings (Windows, Linux and Mac) so it is hard for me to believe that they have designed sorting function for only one of them. But I haven't got chances to test this, sorry.

Comment: Using the current version v7.8.5 I had to save the file, close and and reopen it so that I get the correct order. So apparently you shouldn't make any change to the file after opening it for the function to work correctly!

Comment: Not working in 7.8.9 . Where is TextFX???