# How can I check that files match a list of MD5 checksums on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, batch, checksum, md5

I downloaded a large number of files via this [magnet link](https://tormag.ezpz.work/slv1psql0z) (Apache 2.0 license), then moved the files around between a few devices. I now want to check the integrity of the files.

A file lists MD5 checksums:

[image]

This list is chopped but it contains 770 lines (i.e., 770 MD5 checksums), so I'd like to batch check them. I know how to compute a MD5 checksum on a single file, but I don't know how to check all these files at once.

How can I check that the downloaded files match these MD5 checksums on Windows 10?

Comment: Though this site is not for writing scripts from scratch, you can get help on one you've started. For example, you might use PowerShell, https://medium.com/@mhatrep/how-to-check-verify-checksum-from-windows-command-prompt-9e8cb4c1fe4, to output all filenames and MD5 to a text file (as CSV), and import that and the list of filenames and checksums provided in the magnet file to a spreadsheet, and do an IF EQUAL comparison.

Comment: by magnet link, you'd have torrented it. Wouldn't bitorrent check it for you?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek thanks good point but I've moved the files around a bit after the download completed. I'll add it to the question

Answer (score 2):

MD5 checksum list:

```
ea5774684fe8af0c8dbc73f0587b3ed3  ./tensor00251_000
5e5ac7153ade3bc0258ea8909b411aef  ./tensor00084_000
6358c62cef61d79c24fd223b21798b49  ./tensor00093_000
13f15b98afecc281d84801acf347e220  ./tensor00442_000
392f867c92b96f8c8c7214190f853f2c  ./tensor00277_000
6f5a97ddc80c8d5207d4d165d53121c6  ./tensor00072_000
d6b4317b176fcd0054a70a3a8675daf5  ./tensor00609_000
[...]
```

1. Put `./tensor00XXX_000` into the 1st col, and the MD5 checksums in the 2nd column, by replacing in Notepad++ (gratis):

   [image]

   Corresponding text ([taken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21294092/395857) from [David Yaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480937/david-yaw)):

   ```
   ^(.*)  (.*)$
   ```

   ```
   \2 \1
   ```

   outputs:

   ```
   ./tensor00251_000 ea5774684fe8af0c8dbc73f0587b3ed3
   ./tensor00084_000 5e5ac7153ade3bc0258ea8909b411aef
   ./tensor00093_000 6358c62cef61d79c24fd223b21798b49
   ./tensor00442_000 13f15b98afecc281d84801acf347e220
   ./tensor00277_000 392f867c92b96f8c8c7214190f853f2c
   ./tensor00072_000 6f5a97ddc80c8d5207d4d165d53121c6
   ./tensor00609_000 d6b4317b176fcd0054a70a3a8675daf5
   [...]
   ```
2. [Sort all lines in Notepad++](https://superuser.com/a/777412/116475).

   ```
   ./tensor00000_000 fb91c8c0a7c6eab359115f3641859574
   ./tensor00001_000 db2c5892465c8bf246e481c92f7af378
   ./tensor00002_000 53abd68720183713d250930e2e924171
   ./tensor00003_000 acaa24d88257006a86aae241522215be
   ./tensor00004_000 ce2c7cb1f7a2b438b52a5764443ca715
   ./tensor00005_000 b99a67b86cc73eefe18e34051ebe9a4a
   ./tensor00006_000 474f651f59078b623048a68d9c9a1363
   ./tensor00007_000 cb0ceb7a96b181a78a3c0245567086fb
   [...]
   ```
3. Compute MD5s with [Hasher](https://ericzimmerman.github.io/#!index.md) ([mirror](https://archive.org/details/eric-zimmerman-tools)) (gratis) (thanks Reddit user [evilcalvin122](https://www.reddit.com/user/evilcalvin122) for [mentioning](https://redd.it/1bnwkje) it):

   [image]

   [image]
4. Export the list of MD5 checksums.

   [image]
5. [Compare the 2 lists of MD5 checksums](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73822677/395857).